# postgresql UPDATE error " ERROR: invalid input syntax for type boolean: "

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to make a simple update query on postgresql. I don't really understand the error as there is no boolean value or column type. 
Here is the log :

```
cat=> UPDATE categories SET epekcategoryid='27af8b1e-c0c9-4084-8304-256b2ae0c8b2' and epekparentcategoryid='root' WHERE categoryId='281' and siteid='0' and categoryparentid='-1';
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type boolean: "27af8b1e-c0c9-4084-8304-256b2ae0c8b2"
LINE 1: UPDATE categories SET epekcategoryid='27af8b1e-c0c9-4084-830...
```

The table config :

```
cat=> \d categories;
                Table "public.categories"
        Column        |         Type          | Modifiers 
----------------------+-----------------------+-----------
 categoryid           | character varying(32) | 
 categoryname         | text                  | 
 siteid               | integer               | 
 categoryparentid     | character varying(32) | 
 status               | integer               | default 0
 epekcategoryid       | text                  | 
 epekparentcategoryid | text                  | 
 categorylevel        | character varying(37) | 
 categoryidpath       | character varying(37) |
```

Comment: `WHERE categoryId='281' and siteid=0 and categoryparentid='-1';`

Comment: UPDATE categories SET epekcategoryid='27af8b' and epekparentcategoryid='root' WHERE categoryId='281' and siteid=0 and categoryparentid='-1'; is not working either

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Try:

```
UPDATE categories 
SET epekcategoryid='27af8b1e-c0c9-4084-8304-256b2ae0c8b2',
    epekparentcategoryid='root' 
WHERE categoryId='281' 
  and siteid='0' 
  and categoryparentid='-1';
```

You must separate fields in `SET` part with "`,`" , not with "`AND`"

Comment: Common mistake indeed; using `AND` inside the `SET` part of an `UPDATE` query. Gives unusual errors like this.

Comment: mysql was the bad teacher :) though is a bit weird that we don't use "AND" after SET but we use after "WHERE"

Comment: @mihai It isnt weird, if you think about it. `AND` is an operator. Like `+`, `-` or `*`. In `WHERE` clause it is `true AND false` like `3 + 5`, but in `SET` it becomes weird `var1 = true AND var2 = 3`.